# Login keeps clearing the fields such as username and password when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, web

Here is my code.

```
users.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>A</username>
        <password>c</password>
        <status>Active</status>
    </user>

    <user>

        <username>C</username>
        <password>12345</password>
        <status>Active</status>
    </user>

</users>
```

If i input wrong password of A, All the users in xml change all to blocked.and it automatically change to blocked after 1 login failed only.It didnt even read the 3 times attempt that i created. but i call the php in my condition of ctr in script.before it should blocked.I want to login and input wrong password 3 times then block. and I want A to changed to Blocked but the problem is its all changed even the B.Thank you for your all help.

Comment: That's because when you send the form your inputs get cleared, you need to use `e.preventDefault()` inside a  function in your JS in order for that to not happen.

Comment: Thank u can u give me idea how to put it in JS code?im sorry thank u

Comment: You can just put it anywhere inside your `login()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, whenever a submit button inside form element is clicked, it will submit the form to the url mentioned in action attribute of the form element. As you don't want to post form instead wants to validate username and password in XML itself then you should include **onsubmit="return false;"** in form element.

Try below code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmlogin" name="frmlogin" method="post" action="Login" onsumbit="return false;">
            <p>ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="login_username" id="username"></p>
            <p> ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="password"><br><br>
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Log in" onclick="login()">
            </p>

        </form>
        <script>            
            window.login = function(e)
            {

                if (document.frmlogin.login_username.value == "") 
                {
                    alert("User name is not blank");
                    return;
                }
                else if(document.frmlogin.login_pass.value == "")
                {
                    alert("Password is not blank");
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    var xmlDoc;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {    // IE 5/6
                        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }

                    xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

                    xhttp.open("GET", "users.xml", false);
                    xhttp.send(null);
                    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

                    var ktra=false;
                    var xml=xmlDoc.childNodes[0];

                    var name = xml.childNodes["username"];        
                    var pass=xml.childNodes["password"];
                    for(var i=0;i<xml.childNodes.length;i++){
                        if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName=="user"){
                            name = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[1];
                            pass = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[3];                        
                            if(name.textContent==frmlogin.login_username.value &&pass.textContent==frmlogin.login_pass.value)
                            {
                                alert("Login Successfully !!!");
                                ktra=true;        
                                break;
                            }                        
                        }
                    }
                    if(ktra==false)
                    {
                        alert("Login Failed !!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added your suggestion thank u very much . however whenever i type username and password it doesnt display any alert message.Thank u very much for your help

Comment: For that you should include **name="frmlogin"** in your form as well.

Comment: I added it already but still doesnt display the alert message :( Thank u again

Comment: @alec.aika12345, Have a look at my updated answer. :)

Comment: thank you very much for help you are very nice A lert message is working now you are great thank you how ever  I keep getting Login Failed message even the username and password are in my xml files :( thank you a lot

Comment: hey the problem is for example i have 2 username and password in xml i have a username A and password 12345 the other one is B is the username and password is 12345 . Whenever i try to login it only accept A and password 12345 . B is not working

Comment: the username and password are stored in xml file.However whenever i type my username and password it only allows a username A and password 12345 to login successfully.but if i type B password 12345.Its not working anymore.

Comment: Provide me the xml file with both credentials.

Comment: I have updated code assuming below structure. `<users>
    <user>
        <username>A</username>
        <password>12345</password>
    </user>
 <user>
        <username>B</username>
        <password>12345</password>
    </user>
</users>`

Comment: I want also b to access in login. which if i type B and the password is 12345 it will say login successfully

Comment: whenever i type b it says failed :(

Comment: because you are typing b in small case and the check we have applied is case sensitive, try with B.

Comment: hey There are 3 attempts in this form.What i want to do is if i input wrong pass and username 3 times the status "Active" in xml will change to "Blocked".But the problem is. If i input only one wrong password and it says login failed all the status of the users changed to Blocked. I will update my code.Thank you for your help.